# vb.net 2008 insertion command for ms access is not showing any error but not inserted into table

Tags: vb.net, insert, ms-access-2007

I written some code to insert data of form into ms access database 
it runs successfully and gives no error
but when I see in data base I found there is no data inserted in the database.
what is the problem? 
So guys, please help me.

Here is my vb.net code :

```
Private Sub btnCreateUser_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCreateUser.Click
        Dim con2 As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\OfficeAutomationSystem.accdb; Persist Security Info=False")
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        If Not con2.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            con2.Open()
        End If
        cmd.Connection = con2
        'add data to table
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblUser(emp_id, user_id, pwd, user_type) " & _
                            " values(" & Me.cbEmpId.SelectedItem & ", '" & Me.txtUserId.Text & "','" & _
                            Me.txtPassword.Text & "', '" & Me.cbUserType.SelectedItem & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("running")
End Sub
```

and here is my data base structure of ms access database :

```
field name                    dataYpe
serial_no                     AutoNumber
emp_id                        Number
user_id                       Text
pwd                           Text
user_type                     Text
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Does this condition makes sense If Not con2.State = ConnectionState.Open Then con2.Open() ?

Comment: try to remove if condition and only write con2.Open() and let me know

Comment: Yes, I removed if codition, and same problem exist

Comment: are you able to show messagebox?

Comment: yes I'm able to show msg box

Comment: can you put try catch block and see if you are able to get any exception?

Comment: I done so also right now,  no exception was shown

Comment: are you able to read something from that table? try firing select statement and see if you are getting any results. I dont see any issue in your code

Comment: Yes previous manually inserted data is being fetched and shown to other form

Comment: can you just declare variable and assign your insert statement to that query and let me know how it is showing output

Comment: I already have done so it was same

Comment: can you show me output please?

Comment: Did you checked my answer?

Comment: @AhmadAsjad are you running debug or release version? If you are debugging probably you are inserting or updating in the database copy located at bin\debug folder on your project directory

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to execute this code and just let me know if it works

```
Private Sub btnCreateUser_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCreateUser.Click
    Dim con2 As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\OfficeAutomationSystem.accdb; Persist Security Info=False")
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    If Not con2.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        con2.Open()
    End If
    cmd.Connection = con2
    'add data to table
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblUser(emp_id, user_id, pwd, user_type) " & _
                        " values(" & Convert.ToInt32(Me.cbEmpId.SelectedItem) & ", '" & Me.txtUserId.Text & "','" & _
                        Me.txtPassword.Text & "', '" & Me.cbUserType.SelectedItem & "')"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("running")
End Sub
```

Comment: i asked if my code worked or not? did you tried code in my answer?